# return issue for method in java

Tags: java

Need to write method calculateBoatSpeed() that takes 2 integer parameters. This first is the amount of money a team spent on their boat in dollars. The second is the number of people on the crew who own houses in New Zealand. The method should return how fast the boat will go in knots (a nautical measure of speed equal to about 1.85kph) based on the following formula: one knot for every 10 million spent plus one more for each of the crew who own a house in New Zealand.

I am new in Java, so my effort was not really succeed.

```
int calculateBoatSpeed(int money, int people) {
   int knot= money*1000000+people;
   return knot;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have exactly?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask solutions for your homework.

Comment: @xtreye To be fair he showed effort.  It seems he just meant to use division instead of multiplication.

Comment: The only issue with this question is you didn't show your expected results and usually want to include your actual results as well, particularly when it is an exception or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> based on the following formula: one knot for every 10 million spent
>   plus one more for each of the crew who own a house in New Zealand.

What you did is multiply using `*`.  You want to divide.  Say you have:

- Below 10 million, then you want 0 knots.
- 10 million, then you want 1 knot.
- 20 million, then you want 2 knots.
- 30 million, then you want 3 knots.

To do do this you need money divided by 10 million:

```
int knot = money/10000000 + people;
```

This is assuming that your `people` variable represents the number of people who own a house in New Zealand.  Since we are using `int` data types, we shouldn't have to worrying about decimal values when dividing (using `/`).  It'll just automatically round down to the nearest whole integer.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you've coded (suppose people=0):

- if money = 1 and people=1, your formula produces 1000000 knots.
- money = 2: 2000000 knots
- money = 3: 3000000 knots

mighty fast boat... Think about this a bit

Comment: At money=600 this boat breaks the speed of light.